# error: cannot initialize return object of type 'Type *' with an rvalue of type 'bool'

Tags: javascript, c++

I have this code in JavaScript:

```
// ...

 findNode: function(root, w, h) {
    if (root.used)
      return this.findNode(root.right, w, h) || this.findNode(root.down, w, h);
},

// ...
```

I'm developing an equivalent code in C++ like this:

```
Block *GrowingPacker::findNode(Block *root, float w, float h)
{
    if (root->m_used)
        return findNode(root->m_right, w, h) || findNode(root->m_down, w, h);
}
```

However C++ throws this error at `return` line:

> error: cannot initialize return object of type 'Block *' with an rvalue of type 'bool'

I wonder what is the most elegant approach to prevent the error!

Comment: Use the correct return type?

Comment: Also, if the condition `root->m_used` is false, what do you return then? If you declare a function to return something, you *must* have an explicit `return` statement that actually returns something (of the correct type). Otherwise you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: In C++, `||` is a [boolean operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical), and results in a `bool`.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Unless overloaded... :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : sure, but I wouldn't recommend that as the solution here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (root->m_used)
    return findNode(root->m_right, w, h) || findNode(root->m_down, w, h);
```

returns a boolean but your function expects to return a `Block*`. In Javascript it doesn't matter because there is no strong typing but in C++ the return type of `||` is `bool`.

I think you want this

```
if (root->m_used)
{
    Block* tmp = findNode(root->m_right, w, h);
    if (tmp)
        return tmp;
    else
        return findNode(root->m_down, w, h);
}
```

**AND** you need to add some code to deal with the case when `root->m_used` is false (`return nullptr;` presumably).

Unlike Javascript, C++ is a strongly typed language. Therefore it's really important to enable all the warnings you can on your compiler, so you can catch as many type mismatches and other gotchas as possible.